# Websphere 8 migration - AbstractMethodError: javax/servlet/ServletRequest.getDispatcherType

Tags: migration, websphere

I wanted to upgrade my webapplication from WAS 7.0.0.7 to WAS 8.5. The application deploys normally but as soon as I want to access it I get following exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/servlet/ServletRequest.getDispatcherType()Ljavax /servlet/DispatcherType
```

WAS 8 uses a Servlet 3.0 container but it should be backward compatible with version 2.4 which I am using in my application.

I set the classloading to PARENT LAST and still get the same error.

Websphere is calling getDispatcherType() which is available since Servlet 3.0. Why?

I use following web.xml header

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance including JAR files, containing standard Servlet API, with your application?
Can you list all JAR files included in your EAR?

EDITED following information from asker: you mentioned that you are wrapping the request object. I'm guessing that, when you compiled your code, you were compiling against Servlet 2.4 classes. That's why compilation went through OK (you didn't have to implement `getDispatcherType`). Later, in runtime, you get `AbstractMethodError` because your wrapper implementation doesn't contain an implementation for the now-required `getDispatcherType` method.

The only way for you to resolve this (in my opinion) is to still compile against Servlet 3.0 classes. WebSphere 8.5 will *always* assume that the request is Servlet 3.0, there's no way around it.

Is there a reason why you can't compile against Servlet 3.0 classes?

Comment: I chacked all my jars. Non of them is containing any std. servlet API. What I am doing is wrapping the original request for security reasons. The problem is that websphere thinks it is a java ee 6 request, but I am using a j2ee 1.4 request which does not contain the getDispatcherType method. Do I have any chance to tell websphere to use j2ee 1.4 ServletRequest? Thanks

Comment: As for your question - no, you can't do that (to my knowledge). However, I'm not entirely sure that what you described is actually your problem. AbstractMethodError wouldn't be raised in the condition you had mentioned. I think I know what's going on - I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, I was presuming that as well. Currently an upgrade to Servlet 3.0 is not an option. So I guess there is no other workaround.

Comment: Your runtime environment on WebSphere 8.5 will be a Servlet 3.0 runtime, regardless of what you compile against... unfortunately.